# Wanting to add multiple posts to database from php, but want the added amount for one post

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a page for a friend and I wanted to create a log page that shows me how much "money" they either add or remove from a player but I'm not fully sure how to do this while still updating the current information.

If I am unable to add the amount the player added maybe there is a way that I can just show the updated amount after they added or maybe the before they added. This is just so higher up staff can see any edits

```html
<?php
ob_start();
include('auth.php');
include('admin-auth.php');
include('header.php');

 if(isset($_GET['userId']) && $_GET['userId'] != ''){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE uid='".$_GET['userId']."'";
 $res = $con->query($query);
 if($res->num_rows != 0){
 $data = $res->fetch_assoc();
 }else{
  header("Location: all-users-game-admin.php");
 } 
 }

 if(isset($_POST['uid'])){
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
  $pid = $_REQUEST['pid'];
  $cash = $_REQUEST['cash'];
  $bankacc = $_REQUEST['bankacc'];
  $coplevel = $_REQUEST['coplevel'];
  $mediclevel = $_REQUEST['mediclevel'];
  $query = "UPDATE players SET name = '".$name."', pid = '".$pid."', cash = '".$cash."', bankacc = '".$bankacc."', coplevel = '".$coplevel."', mediclevel = '".$mediclevel."' WHERE uid = '".$_REQUEST['uid']."'";
  
         $name2 = $_REQUEST['name']; 
  $cash = $_REQUEST['cash'];
  $bankacc = $_REQUEST['bankacc'];
  $ammount = $_REQUEST['ammount'];
  $mediclevel = $_REQUEST['mediclevel'];
  if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   $staff = $_SESSION['user'];
  }else{
   $staff = '';
  }
  $query = "UPDATE money-log SET name = '".$name2."', ammount = '".$cash."', bankacc = '".$bankacc."', coplevel = '".$coplevel."', mediclevel = '".$mediclevel."' WHERE uid = '".$_REQUEST['uid']."'";    
  $result = $con->query($query);
  if($result){
   echo "<script>alert('Data Updated.')</script>";
   header('location:all-users-game-admin.php');
  }
 }
 
 ?>
<style>
.profile_details textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.update-edit button { 

background: rgba(88,134,23,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(88,134,23,1) 0%, rgba(139,190,72,1) 53%, rgba(88,134,23,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(88,134,23,1)), color-stop(53%, rgba(139,190,72,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(88,134,23,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(88,134,23,1) 0%, rgba(139,190,72,1) 53%, rgba(88,134,23,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(88,134,23,1) 0%, rgba(139,190,72,1) 53%, rgba(88,134,23,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(88,134,23,1) 0%, rgba(139,190,72,1) 53%, rgba(88,134,23,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(88,134,23,1) 0%, rgba(139,190,72,1) 53%, rgba(88,134,23,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#588617', endColorstr='#588617', GradientType=1 );

padding: 7px 40px;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
}
</style>
<div class="title">
     <h1>Update User</h1>
  
    </div>
    <div class="profile_details">
    <div class="profile_info">
     <h1>Update User Detail</h1>
  <form method="post" >
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pro_row">
                 <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username" readonly value="<?php echo $data['name']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid"
    value="<?php echo $data['uid']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

   <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pro_row">
                 <label>Steam ID</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pid" value="<?php echo $data['pid']; ?>"
     readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pro_row">
                 <label>Cash</label>
                    <input type="number" name="cash"  value="<?php echo $data['cash']; ?>"
     required>
                </div>
            </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pro_row">
                 <label>Bank</label>
                    <input type="number" name="bankacc" value="<?php echo $data['bankacc']; ?>"
     required>
                </div>
            </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pro_row">
                 <label>Cop Level</label>
                    <input type="number" name="coplevel"  min="0" max="7" value="<?php echo $data['coplevel']; ?>"
     required>
                </div>
            </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pro_row">
                 <label>Medic Level</label>
                    <input type="number" name="mediclevel"  min="0" max="1" value="<?php echo $data['mediclevel']; ?>"
     required>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
         </div>
    <div class="update-edit">
  <button type="submit" id="update-button" >Update User</button>
  <a onclick ="makeTextFieldsEditable();" href="<?php echo SITE_URL."all-users-game-admin.php"; ?>">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
 <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: please explain your requirement clearly..

Comment: The Idea is when the person updates the database, it will update the original and also send a post to another database that logs the actions stating how much money the person either added or removed from the person. For example if bob had $5 in there bank and I added $2 to make it 7 it would say. Hadyetm for staffname then amount is 2 because I added 2 dollars to the person